# Create new columns with length of groups in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to create a new data frame which is grouped by one column (i.e. Petal.Width below) and has new columns created from the groups of another variable (i.e. Species) and with the number of observations from each of the Species groups. I assume dplyr is able to do this but I cant quite get what I need

I have tried this code but it returns the length of all observations in Species rather than the length of each group (i.e. all columns have the same data)

```
iris=as.data.frame(iris)
groups= iris %>%
  group_by(Petal.Width) %>%
  summarize(Seposa=length(Species == "seposa"),
        Versicolor=length(Species == "versicolor"),
        Virginica=length(Species == "virginica"))
```

I assume I am just making a small error somewhere. Any help please!

Comment: Sounds like you want `sum(...)` instead of `length(...)`. Also, I think you mis-spelt "setosa" as "seposa"...

Answer (score 1):

As @Z.Lin notes you need sum() instead of length in your example, but using this method it's critical that you don't mis-spell.

Here's another way to do it:

```
library(dplyr)

iris=as.data.frame(iris)

iris %>%
  group_by(Petal.Width, Species) %>%
  count() %>%
  spread(Species, n, fill = 0)
```